# How can I read a EXPLAIN ANALYZE in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance

I have read a bunch of resources on the internet and the official documentation of PostgreSQL and I still don't know how to interpret the result of a EXPLAIN ANALYZE. I'm using PostgreSQL 12.8 and I have the following result when executing the EXPLAIN ANALYZE command:

[image]

**EDIT with text**

```
QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------
Nested Loop (cost=138604.33.. 149260.39 rows=1 width=238) (actual time=448.894.. 162293.701 rows=372 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (s.id = setting_aud.id)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 69006
  Buffers: shared hit=38723745
  -> Gather (cost=1000.00.. 10052.82 rows=1 width=234) (actual time=0.264..0.799 rows=372 loops=1)
    Workers Planned: 2
    Workers Launched: 2
    Buffers: shared hit=7845
    -> Parallel Seq Scan on settings (cost=0.00..9052.72 rows=1 width=234) (actual time=5.367..15.796 rows=124 loops=3)
      Filter: (active AND ((type)::text = 'AgePlateLever'::text))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 76875
      Buffers: shared hit=7845
  -> Finalize GroupAggregate (cost=137604.33. . 139076.80 rows=5812 width=12) (actual time=436.029..436.206 rows=186 loops=372)
    Group Key: setting_aud.id
    Buffers: shared hit=13063859
    -> Gather Merge (cost=137604.33..138960.56 rows=11624 width=12) (actual time=436.022..436.121 rows=554 loops=372)
      Workers Planned: 2
      Workers Launched: 2
      Buffers: shared hit=13063859
      -> Sort (cost=136604.31..136618.84 rows=5812 width=12) (actual time=431.252..431.278 rows=480 loops=1116)
        Sort Key: setting_aud.id
        Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 59kB
        Worker 0: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 59kB
        Worker 1: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 59kB
        Buffers: shared hit=38715900
        -> Partial HashAggregate (cost=136182.79..136240.91 rows=5812 width=12) (actual time=430.954..431.065 rows=741 loops=1116)
          Group Key: setting_aud.id
          Buffers: shared hit=38709948
          -> Parallel Seq Scan on setting_aud (cost=0.00.. 129655.88 rows=1305384 width=12) (actual time=0.017..282.585 rows=1040198 loops=1116)
            Filter: ((revision_type <> 2) AND ((type)::text = 'AgeplateLever'::text))
            Rows Removed by Filter: 324937
            Buffers: shared hit=38709948
Planning Time: 0.332 ms
Execution Time: 162294.083 ms
```

How can I know where to put indexes looking into these results? How can I know how many iterations are executed in the `Nested Loop` join?

**EDIT 2**

I have added the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX setting_type_active_id_idx ON setting (type, active, id);
CREATE INDEX setting_aud_type_revision_type_id_revision_id_idx ON setting_aud (type, revision_type, id, revision_id);
```

And also executed EXPLAIN with VERBOSE option in order to see more information as suggested by Laurenz Albe, the results now are better:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Merge Join  (cost=139152.19..140705.34 rows=1 width=238) (actual time=468.645..470.827 rows=372 loops=1)                                                                                                                                                |
  Output: s.id, s.setting_key, s.type, s.cap_id, s.current_value, s.source, s.rationale, s.created_date, s.last_modified_date, s.model_year, s.batch_adjustment_id, s.active, s.last_activated_at, s.setting_metadata_id, (max(setting_aud.revision_id))|
  Inner Unique: true                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
  Merge Cond: (s.id = setting_aud.id)                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
  Buffers: shared hit=105643                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
  ->  Index Scan using setting_type_active_id_idx on db_schema.setting s  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=234) (actual time=0.022..0.385 rows=372 loops=1)                                                                                     |
        Output: s.id, s.setting_key, s.type, s.cap_id, s.current_value, s.source, s.rationale, s.created_date, s.last_modified_date, s.model_year, s.batch_adjustment_id, s.active, s.last_activated_at, s.setting_metadata_id                          |
        Index Cond: (((s.type)::text = 'AgePlateLever'::text) AND (s.active = true))                                                                                                                                                                    |
        Buffers: shared hit=385                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
  ->  Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=139151.77..140624.24 rows=5812 width=12) (actual time=468.620..470.347 rows=372 loops=1)                                                                                                                           |
        Output: setting_aud.id, max(setting_aud.revision_id)                                                                                                                                                                                            |
        Group Key: setting_aud.id                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
        Buffers: shared hit=105258                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
        ->  Gather Merge  (cost=139151.77..140508.00 rows=11624 width=12) (actual time=468.610..470.165 rows=1109 loops=1)                                                                                                                              |
              Output: setting_aud.id, (PARTIAL max(setting_aud.revision_id))                                                                                                                                                                            |
              Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
              Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
              Buffers: shared hit=105258                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
              ->  Sort  (cost=138151.75..138166.28 rows=5812 width=12) (actual time=465.746..465.780 rows=618 loops=3)                                                                                                                                  |
                    Output: setting_aud.id, (PARTIAL max(setting_aud.revision_id))                                                                                                                                                                      |
                    Sort Key: setting_aud.id                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 59kB                                                                                                                                                                                                |
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 59kB                                                                                                                                                                                     |
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 59kB                                                                                                                                                                                     |
                    Buffers: shared hit=105258                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
                    Worker 0: actual time=463.883..463.923 rows=740 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                             |
                      Buffers: shared hit=34816                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
                    Worker 1: actual time=465.030..465.070 rows=740 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                             |
                      Buffers: shared hit=37348                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
                    ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=137730.24..137788.36 rows=5812 width=12) (actual time=465.461..465.568 rows=741 loops=3)                                                                                                           |
                          Output: setting_aud.id, PARTIAL max(setting_aud.revision_id)                                                                                                                                                                  |
                          Group Key: setting_aud.id                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
                          Buffers: shared hit=105242                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
                          Worker 0: actual time=463.576..463.685 rows=740 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                       |
                            Buffers: shared hit=34808                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
                          Worker 1: actual time=464.728..464.834 rows=740 loops=1                                                                                                                                                                       |
                            Buffers: shared hit=37340                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on db_schema.setting_aud  (cost=0.00..131129.27 rows=1320193 width=12) (actual time=0.017..304.923 rows=1052528 loops=3)                                                                     |
                                Output: setting_aud.id, setting_aud.revision_id                                                                                                                                                                         |
                                Filter: ((setting_aud.revision_type <> 2) AND ((setting_aud.type)::text = 'AgePlateLever'::text))                                                                                                                       |
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 328028                                                                                                                                                                                          |
                                Buffers: shared hit=105242                                                                                                                                                                                              |
                                Worker 0: actual time=0.006..303.967 rows=1044836 loops=1                                                                                                                                                               |
                                  Buffers: shared hit=34808                                                                                                                                                                                             |
                                Worker 1: actual time=0.013..304.850 rows=1117851 loops=1                                                                                                                                                               |
                                  Buffers: shared hit=37340                                                                                                                                                                                             |
Planning Time: 0.234 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |
Execution Time: 470.919 ms                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
```

**Now is using index scan for `setting` table, but why is still doing a Parallel Seq Scan on setting_aud and not an index scan? Why the loops were reduced?**

Comment: I have updated the question with the text of the execution plan.

Comment: The loops are reduced  because you no longer have a nested **loop** join. My answer explains why the index is not used.

Comment: Ok ok, understood. Can I remove the index of setting_aud table in this case right?

Comment: It is not needed for this query. But check if other queries need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only potential place where an index could help is

```
-> Parallel Seq Scan on setting_aud (cost=0.00.. 129655.88 rows=1305384 width=12) (actual time=0.017..282.585 rows=1040198 loops=1116)
   Filter: ((revision_type <> 2) AND ((type)::text = 'AgeplateLever'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 324937
   Buffers: shared hit=38709948
```

But an index won't really help much here, because only few rows are filtered out. What *might* help is adding all required columns to the index so you can get an index-only scan, but to determine which columns those are you would need the result of `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)`.

However, the main problem is probably the misestimate on the scan on `setting` (124 instead of 1), which leads the optimizer to choose a nested loop join, so that `setting_aud` is scanned 1116 times. to fix that, try to improve the estimate:

1. Perhaps `ANALYZE setting` is already enough.
2. If not, improve the statistics:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE setting ALTER type SET STATISTICS 1000;
   ANALYZE setting;
   ```
3. If that is still not enough, try extended statistics:

   ```
   CREATE STATISTICS some_name (dependencies) ON type, active FROM setting;
   ANALYZE setting;
   ```

Then hopefully a hash or merge join will be chosen, and the performance will improve.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have updated my question with more information and the indexes I added in order to improve it, give me one sec to execute the ANALYZE in the setting table

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to execute ANALYZE in the table, is there any way of improve the query after the indexes I added?